# React - Sorting Table Columns Inside a Map() Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, chakra-ui

I am trying to sort a table (ascending/descending) when my table header data is placed inside a .map() method (see line 73 of the codesandbox link in this post).

I can get the hand emoji to change onClick, but no sorting takes place. I think it may have something to do with passing an object to the map method, and not an individual string or numeric value as found in the codesandbox that I have based this functionality on. Here is the original sandbox that I am modelling after:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/table-sorting-example-ur2z9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

...and here is my codesandbox with my data structure that I need to sort:
https://codesandbox.io/s/table-sorting-example-forked-dofhj?file=/src/App.js

What can I change in order to get each column to be sortable? Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Button,
  Table,
  Thead,
  Tbody,
  Flex,
  Tooltip,
  Tr,
  Th,
  Td
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

//Table Headers
const TABLE_HEADERS = [
  { name: "ID Number" },
  { name: "User Type" },
  { name: "User Category" },
  { name: "User Interest" }
];

const useSortableData = (items, config = null) => {
  const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = React.useState(config);

  const sortedItems = React.useMemo(() => {
    let sortableItems = [...items];
    if (sortConfig !== null) {
      sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[sortConfig.key] < b[sortConfig.key]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === "ascending" ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (a[sortConfig.key] > b[sortConfig.key]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === "ascending" ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }
    return sortableItems;
  }, [items, sortConfig]);

  const requestSort = (key) => {
    let direction = "ascending";
    if (
      sortConfig &&
      sortConfig.key === key &&
      sortConfig.direction === "ascending"
    ) {
      direction = "descending";
    }
    setSortConfig({ key, direction });
  };

  return { items: sortedItems, requestSort, sortConfig };
};

const ProductTable = (props) => {
  const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(
    props.myUserErrorTypes
  );

  const getClassNamesFor = (name) => {
    if (!sortConfig) {
      return;
    }
    return sortConfig.key === name ? sortConfig.direction : undefined;
  };
  return (
    <Table>
      <caption>User Error Types</caption>
      <Thead>
        <Tr>
          {TABLE_HEADERS.map(({ name, description, isNumeric }) => (
            <Th key={name} isNumeric={isNumeric}>
              <Button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => requestSort(name)}
                className={getClassNamesFor(name)}
              >
                <Tooltip label={description} aria-label={description}>
                  {name}
                </Tooltip>
              </Button>
            </Th>
          ))}
        </Tr>
      </Thead>
      <Tbody>
        {items.map((error) => {
          const { userNumber, userType, errorId, errorCategory } = error;
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={errorId}>
              <Tr id={errorId} key={errorId}>
                <Td>{userNumber}</Td>
                <Td>{userType}</Td>
                <Td>{errorId}</Td>
                <Td>{errorCategory}</Td>
                <Td textAlign="center">
                  <Flex justify="justifyContent"></Flex>
                </Td>
              </Tr>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </Tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ProductTable
        myUserErrorTypes={[
          {
            userNumber: 1234567890,
            userType: "SuperUser",
            errorId: 406,
            errorCategory: "In-Progress"
          },
          {
            userNumber: 4859687937,
            userType: "NewUser",
            errorId: 333,
            errorCategory: "Complete"
          }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items are being sorted by the table header name (e.g. `'ID Number'`) since you're calling `requestSort` with the name. Add an `id` property to the objects in the `TABLE_HEADERS` array matching the property name (e.g. `userNumber`) in the data objects and pass it as an argument to both the `requestSort` and `getClassNamesFor` functions.

```
const TABLE_HEADERS = [
  { name: 'ID Number', id: 'userNumber' },
  { name: 'User Type', id: 'userType' },
  { name: 'User Category', id: 'errorId' },
  { name: 'User Interest', id: 'errorCategory' },
]
```

```
{
  TABLE_HEADERS.map(({ name, id }) => (
    <Th key={id}>
      <Button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => requestSort(id)}
        className={getClassNamesFor(id)}
      >
        {name}
      </Button>
    </Th>
  ))
}
```

You're also trying to use the `description` and `isNumeric` values from the header object but they are both `undefined`. You might want to add those properties to the objects in the `TABLE_HEADERS` array.

[image: Edit on CodeSandbox]

Comment: Thanks - that works - but what if my TABLE_HEADERS are coming in asynchronously from a server and they don't have the 'id' key?

Comment: @Jon Once you have the data and the table headers from the API, you can add the id property to the headers using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).